# How to group actions for export as single animations, for Unity?

Tags: animation, unity

**Issue:** Each object gets its own animation as a new action. So if I animate two arms, they will be imported as two different animations in Unity.

**Requirement:** I want to be able to combine multiple actions into one, but still be able to create multiple animations for the same model.

**Example**: I may have two arm models. I want both of their animations to be in a single action (for Unity), but I also want to be able to create multiple animations for them, like idle, walk, run, etc.

Comment: When you export to fbx disable "All Actions" and "NLA Tracks" in the Exporter window's animation tab and export an own file for each animation.

Comment: I have a similar problem, I have 2 rigs (character & weapon) I need to export the rigs with their actions but is just exported the animation of one rig (active) Did you fix it?

Comment: @GurpreetSinghMatharoo you ever found a solution?